# Ruby Rails4 and devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help!

> I m a beginner for ruby on rails.

I am updating values from simple web form into sqlite3 database.

Problem is only email & password fields are getting inserted into table. first_name, last_name , etc are showing value 'nil'

I am using DEVISE for authentication setup.

*Here is my code for user.rb:*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                  :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name
end
```

*code from  my web form*

```
<div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>
     <div><%= f.label :profile_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :profile_name %></div>
```

*and a code excerpt from my migrate folder:*

```
def changed
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :profile_name

 t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
 t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
```

**Please HELP!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **[Devise's Github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)** actually has some really good information on how to get it installed and working. There's also a **[RailsCast about Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)**

It seems you're very confused about how Devise works, and I'd highly recommend brushing up on it!

---

**Migration**

First of all, Devise creates its own migration which will have a lot of columns inside. This is generated by Devise with the following commands in your Ruby CMD:

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise MODEL
```

Once you've ran this latter command, run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

This will allow you to create the database, and then you've just got to create the views:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

This creates the login, register & other views which devise uses to help keep authentication running on your app.

Comment: Thanks for your information rich! I was aware of the commands you quoted. But yes , I need to look on github page of devise for improvement. Thanks a lot!! 
Good Luck!!!
Help me in future :)

Answer (score 0):

In rails4 supports strong parameters and attr_accessible is deprecated in Rails4.
so add following code and try to run the i hope this will help you.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```